# Can we get previous tweet using Twitter Streaming API?

Tags: php, twitter

I am working with **Twitter REST API** [PHP] for a month. Now I try **STREAMING API** because **REST API** has several downsides.

I use [fennb/phirehose](https://github.com/fennb/phirehose) to work with **Streaming API**.

But after several trial and error, I realise that I can't got past/previous tweets using **Streaming API**.

- I run the script
- I post tweet
- console/cmd will catch my tweet immediately
- I stop the script
- I post tweet
- I run the script
- console not return any result.

The problem is, in programming and server, sometimes shit happen. Let's call it server down or lost internet connection. I will never get all previous tweet which posted when my server down. (I have 40 search term and more later).

**So. i wanna ask:**

1. Can we get previous tweet using **Streaming API**?
2. How to prevent/solve this case (console throw error, server restart, internet down, etc)?

Comment: @Trix thanks for editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter's basic streaming API is realtime and about 1% of the actual firehouse of Tweets. You cannot retrieve older Tweets via the stream, and would need to fallback to the basic REST API to check for anything missed in the event of disconnection.

Twitter's enterprise data APIs include historical PowerTrack which can let you get older Tweets, as well as a replay capability in the event of disconnection, but these APIs are commercial.

Comment: your answer is exactly same with phirehose owner answer (he answered yesterday). but, i want to know how to get commercial API? i need to contact gnip or twitter?

Comment: Gnip is part of Twitter. You can use https://gnip.com/contact to request the sales team gets in touch. The data products are expensive and not generally suitable for hobby projects, they are intended for enterprise users.

Comment: this not hobby projects. this my company projects. but i dont think my company will want to spend higher than $500/month. because we already rent vendor twitter apps for $1000/month. We try to develop because we want to decrease our spending. i think its better to rent more VPS server to get this done. thank you very much for your help. i appreciate this

Comment: Apologies for suggesting that this was not your use case, I just wanted to set expectations :-)

Comment: Also please be aware of Twitter terms of service regarding use multiple stream connections and / or app keys to circumvent restrictions. I hope your development goes well!